# openpyxl select only two categories instead of 20 while inserting a barchart using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

filename = 'C:/work/dev/example.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'data1'

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

chart_sheet = workbook.create_sheet(title='test5')

# Create the bar chart
chart = BarChart()

# Set the category range for the chart (using the first column)
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=25, max_row=2)

# Set the data range for the chart (excluding the first column)
categories = Reference(sheet, min_col=6, min_row=1,  max_col=25, max_row=1)



# Add the data and category labels to the chart
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(categories)

chart.legend = None

# Add the chart to the chart sheet
chart_sheet.add_chart(chart, "A1")

# Save the workbook
workbook.save(filename)
```

here is the above code where I was able to create a bar chart in a new sheet by fetching data in existing sheet called data the only issue is it is only plotting company1 and company2 which is grouped together all the data point

This is how excel sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpbSt.png)

And here is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HcST.png)

how to get all the companies in x-axis?